# "TCP_MISS" with squid proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I have set up a squid proxy on EC2, and I'm trying to use it from behind a corporate firewall. After configuring firefox to use my proxy, I tried to surf to yahoo.com. The browser seems to hang as if handling an extremely long running request. Checking the squid logs I see:

```
1431354246.891  11645 xxx.0.xx.xxx TCP_MISS/200 7150 CONNECT www.yahoo.com:443 username HIER_DIRECT/xx.xxx.XX.xx-
```

So far, I don't have a good explanation of most of these entries , but from http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#access.log , I've found that:

```
MISS = The response object delivered was the network response object.
```

What does this mean? Is anything I can do to connect to the outside internet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been asked a long time ago, but maybe someone can still use this...

This means you connected to squid and the request was made to yahoo using the TCP protocol that HTTP uses. Furthermore, the MISS means it's a cache miss, squid doesn't have this page stored.

The reason for the hanging might be caused by the response being caught somewhere along the line (corporate firewall, maybe? local firewall?) or even misconfiguration of the proxy.

For more, perhaps you should search on https://serverfault.com, for example this is a good starting point, then you can narrow down the problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/514716/whats-the-minimum-required-squid-config-to-make-a-public-proxy-server